# Using force option in cypress click command

Tags: cypress

Recently we saw one regression issue on our UI , where one of the toggle button was not able to select. But our UI automation was passing all the testcases.
on further checking, we saw we were using {force: true} option for selecting that button. And force option we are using in multiple places for different elements

Quick doubts to avoid such regression issues

1: Is force option is not recommended to use in cypress..? we starting using for some elements because of random failures

2: Any reason why manually button was not able to select but via force:true we could able to select

3:Any tips to avoid such issues//

I searched cypress document , but didnt found any other alternatives

Comment: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/interacting-with-elements#Forcing